# Simplest way to put everything under http://localhost:3000/app instead of http://localhost:3000/ in React

Tags: reactjs

How to change root path of React app, to be specific: all html, css and js will be under http://localhost:3000/app instead of just http://localhost:3000?

Is there a simple way to amend existing app to just have one more level?

(this is useful when having reverse proxy e.g. nginx or apache in front of the React)

Note that compiled project should also have the same /app prefix everywhere

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution for compiled code!

Add to `package.json`

```
  "homepage": "/app/",
```

Add to `index.html`

```
<head>
  <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
</head>
```

Now build the app with `npm run build`

Copy files to web server (e.g. Nginx) `cp -r build /usr/share/nginx/html/app`

Access this at:

```
http://localhost/app
```

So all paths should have prefix `app/` now